# MailChimp campaign not showing up in Drupal 7

Tags: emails

I set up the MailChimp (https://drupal.org/project/mailchimp) module by following the readme file. I've enabled all the Mailchimp modules and added the API key to my drupal instance. I've created and Sent one campaign through MailChimp however, when I go to /admin/config/services/mailchimp/campaigns the page is blank. I've cleared the cache but the page is still blank. I was expecting to see the campaign I sent earlier but it is not there.

What am I doing wrong or missing?

Answer (score 2):

You need to have libraries 2.0 module installed and download a special mailchimp API library.  https://drupal.org/documentation/modules/mailchimp

Answer (score 2):

I think you use mcc module for create mailchimp for node. when you disable this module its show list of all campaign which you created.

you can also use mailchimp function for getting list of campaign:

$campaigns = mailchimp_campaign_load_multiple();